# Average rating with ratings stored in 2 columns

Tags: mysql, average

I have searched the site and all answers similar refer to a separate rating table, not an implementation like this.

I have converted a wordpress site to a self built website in PHP/MYSQL, imagine the actual post being a review and the comments being actual reviews relating to the original post.

The problem I am having is I have a rating field for the posts table and a rating field for each comment entered.

I am trying to use the aliases AvgRating as one, however it only returns the comments ratings(c.rating), if that line is removed it brings back the review rating from the posts table, Is there a way to join the aliases as the average rating? Obviously only this part is wrong, but doesn't throw an error.

```
SELECT p.post_id
     , p.title
     , AVG(p.rating) AvgRating
     , AVG(c.rating) AvgRating -- returns average from comments field, if line is removed will return posts rating value instead..
  FROM posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN comments c 
    ON p.post_id = c.post_id 
 WHERE p.post_id = $post_id
   AND c.post_id = $post_id
   AND active = 1  
 GROUP 
    BY p.post_id
     , p.title;
```

I am trying the get the average for schema aggregrate count markup. Is there a way of achieving this in one query? Or is my only option to use 2 queries returning the 2 averages and using a PHP function to return the average between both?

Here's a test database:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`content` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`active` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_submitted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2157 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`cmt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
`comment` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`cmt_author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cmt_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cmt_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`cmt_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=397 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `cat_id`, `rating`, `title`, `content`, `date_added`, `author`, `active`, `slug`, `user_submitted`) VALUES
(2, 9, 5, 'site1.com', 'Original post review body', '2010-05-07 05:00:00', '', 1, 'site1-com', 1);

INSERT INTO `comments` (`cmt_id`, `post_id`, `rating`, `comment`, `cmt_author`, `cmt_email`, `ip_address`, `cmt_date`, `cmt_status`) VALUES
(1, 2, 5, 'it is a good site test review', 'Anonymous', '', '', '2010-01-06 21:51:00', 1),
(2, 2, 3, 'it is an average site test review', 'Anonymous', '', '', '2010-01-06 20:51:00', 1),
(3, 2, 1, 'it is an bad site test review', 'Anonymous', '', '', '2010-01-06 23:51:00', 1),
(4, 2, 0, 'neutral test review', 'Anonymous', '', '', '2010-01-06 22:51:00', 1),
(5, 2, 2, 'below average test review', 'Anonymous', '', '', '2010-01-06 22:51:00', 1);
```

Query to run:

```
SELECT p.post_id
 , p.title
 , AVG(p.rating) AvgRating
 , AVG(c.rating) AvgRating -- returns average from comments field, if line is removed will return posts rating value instead..
FROM posts p
LEFT 
JOIN comments c 
ON p.post_id = c.post_id 
WHERE p.post_id = 2
AND active = 1  
GROUP 
BY p.post_id
 , p.title;
```

Running this in PHPmyadmin on a test database returns: AvgRating: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

(which was to be expected, as I wrongly assumed it would put the averages of both into one instance of the alias column avgRating)

Results:

```
post_id  title      AvgRating  AvgRating
   2     site1.com  5.0000     2.2000
```

So that is correct in a sense, but how to factor in the original post rating of 5.000 into the comments rating 2.2000?

The desired result should be 2.6667 not 2.2000 because (5+5+3+1+0+2) /6 = 2.6667. 2.2000 is only the average of the comments ratings, and is not factoring in the original post rating of 5.000

Comment: Am I missing something? This seems too obvious. Both aliases are the same. So in PHP the first alias is overwritten by the second.

Comment: Also `AND c.post_id = $post_id` is redundant (and, in fact, counter-productive, as it renders the LEFT [OUTER] JOIN as an INNER JOIN).

Comment: Hi yes, Sorry I realised that was happening, I am struggling to get the averages from both tables, the averages are coming from the comments rating field which is great, but need to factor in the original rating from the posts rating field and somehow add that to the overall average.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have updated the question as I could not get SQL fiddle to work even though it stated it created the schema, running a query stated that the posts table does not exist.

Comment: What would the desired result be? (5+2.2)/2 ??

Comment: I've updated the question after running the query in PHPmyadmin, even if I changed the additional alias table name, how is it possible to get the average rating as one value?

Comment: Yeah, you can solve this more elegantly, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with UNION...

```
SELECT post_id
     , AVG(rating) avg_rating
  FROM 
     ( SELECT post_id
            , rating FROM posts
        UNION 
          ALL
       SELECT post_id
            , rating 
         FROM comments
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY post_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad65d/14

Comment: Hey, I tried to explain the best I could and really appreciate the help, it's complex as I have never attempted it before, I made it clear that the average returned was not factoring in the original posts table rating and only ever returning the comments average ratings. How I came up with the desired result was to add another row under the comments rating field to the exact same value as the posts rating field, then run the query.

Comment: Hey thanks! That is a much cleaner way of dong it! Infact the function I created was untested on the live site when I posted it, though it worked on the test database as intended but when testing live it as above, it didn't take into account if the original rating was zero etc. But now I have it taking into account all those conditions so it works great, but when I have more time, I will modify it and use your method, as it is a much cleaner way. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a mixture of PHP & SQL: (I was originally looking for a less messy way to do this in SQL though)

```
<?php
 include_once('includes/dbcon.php');

foreach($db->query("SELECT 
p.post_id,
p.title,
p.rating AS oreview,
SUM(c.rating) AS creview
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = 2 where active=1 
GROUP BY 
p.post_id,
p.title") as $ratr) {
//get count
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id=posts.post_id where comments.post_id=2 AND active=1');
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
$numreviews = $row_count+1;
//echo $ratr['creview'] ."<br>";
//echo $ratr['oreview'] ."<br>";
echo ($ratr['creview']+$ratr['oreview'])/$numreviews;
 }
 ?>
```

**Or as a function with example:**

```
function aggRating($db,$post_id){
    foreach($db->query("SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    p.rating AS oreview,
    SUM(c.rating) AS creview
    FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = ".$post_id." where active=1 
    GROUP BY 
    p.post_id,
    p.title") as $ratr) {
//get review count
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id=posts.post_id where comments.post_id=".$post_id." AND active=1");
    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $numreviews = $row_count+1; //add original post review to total
echo round(($ratr['creview']+$ratr['oreview'])/$numreviews,2);
         }
  }

//return result (2.67)
echo aggRating($db,$post_id); 
?>
```

Comment: If you solve your own problem that's great and we love it when people share that with future readers, but please do so only using the answer section and not by modifying the question.